# C languages word weight distinct

Tags: c

In this problem you should read a set of words. Each word is composed only by letters in the range a-z and A-Z. Each letter has a specific value, the letter a is worth 1, letter b is worth 2 and so on until letter z that is worth 26.

Write a program to compute the weight of the word for each test case.
The weight of the word is computed by adding the values of the words distinct letters.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int wordDist(char letter){ 
    int count; 
    char str [200]; 
    int i; 
    char letters [26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',
                    'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'‌​,
                    'u','v', 'w','x','y','z'}; 
    for(i=0; i<26; i++){ 
        if(letter = letters[i]) 
            return i+1; 
    }
} 
int main() {
    int T, n, t; 
    scanf("%d", &T); 
    for(t = 1; t <= T; t++){ //count = 0;   
        //printf("%d\n",wordDist(str));
    } return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question to add the code. That comment is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

ASCII characters are simply sequential 8 bit values i.e. 'a'=97, 'b'=98, 'A'=65, 'B'=66.

Therefore, to get the 'weight' of a letter, you simply compute your lowercase char minus 'a'+1 or your uppercase char minus 'A' + 1.

So in pseudocode (because I'm not going to write your homework for you:

```
function char_weight(c):
    weight = c - 'A'
    if c greater than or equal to 'a':
        weight = weight + 'a' - 'A'
    return weight

function word_weight(word):
   add char_weight(each_char) to total
   return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the words are separated by one space, the code would look something like this :

```
c=fgetc(stdin);
while(c!=EOF) {
    s=0;
    while(c!=' ') { //while we are in a word
           if(c>='a' && c<='z')
               s+=(c-'a'+1);
           else
               s+=(c-'A'+1);
           c=fgetc(stdin);
    }
    printf("%d\n", s);
}
```

This `s+=(c-'a'+1);` is possible due to ASCII code. In ASCII  (American Standard Code for Information Interchange), every character has a value : *'a' = 97*. This means that you don't have to write `s+=(c-97+1)` (which works too), but you just don't have to remember the ASCII code of any character.

To convince yourself, write something like :

```
if('b' == 98)
    printf("They are equal);
else
    printf("They aren't equal");
```

To proof that you can add a number to a character :

```
char ch;
ch='a';
ch=ch+1;
if(c == 'b')
  printf( "you can add a number to a character" );
```